# What is happening when pointer arithmetic is used as an argument to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, mergesort

I'm taking an introductory c++ course where we are learning how to implement mergesort. I am trying to walk myself through each step in the code, but there is one piece that is tripping me up:

```
1. void mergeSort(int *x, int len){
2. if (len>1){
3. int newLen=len/2;
4. mergeSort(x, newLen);
5. mergeSort(x+newLen,len-newLen);
6. int *newSeq;
7. newSeq=new int[len];
8. mTwoSeq(x, x+newLen, newSeq,newLen, len-newLen);
9.  for(int i=0;i<len;++i){
10.   x[i]=newSeq[i];
11.     }
12. delete[] newSeq;
13.   }
14. }
```

What is happening in line 5? It is my understanding that when we call "x+i" where x is an array of pointers, we are asking for the computer to give us the address of the piece of memory that holds the ith piece of data. If this is the case, I'm not entirely sure how this fits in here. If anyone knows what's happening in that function call, I'd be very glad to know. Thanks!

Comment: `x` is not an array of pointers. It is a pointer to `int`, which may or may not point to an element of an array.

Answer (score 3):

Lines 4 and 5 treat the array as two "halves" which will each then be sorted by a recursive call.  The first argument of the call on line 5 (`x + newLen`) is computing the address of the element that is (roughly) in the middle of the array since `newLen` is (about) half of the length.  (I say "roughly" and "about" here because this depends on whether the original value of `len` is odd or even.)

You are correct that `x + newLen` is using "pointer arithmetic", since `x` is a pointer.  Assuming, as is the cast on many/most systems, the size of an `int` on your system is 4 bytes, then as an example, if `newLen` is 12, the pointer that results from doing `x + newLen` will actually be an address in memory that is **48** greater than the original value of `x` (because pointer arithmetic takes into account the size of the type of element being pointed to).  This will mean that `x + newLen` points to an integer 12 spots from the beginning of the array.

Finally, the commenter above was right in correcting you.  `x` is not an array of pointers.  Rather, it's a pointer to an integer, which is presumably at the first spot in the array (or sub-array) of integers to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

An unusual thing about C++ (and C) is that when you declare an array, like this:

int a[5];

The name 'a' is actually equivalent to &(a[0]), the address of the first element of the array.  That is to say, when you use 'a' in an expression, it's a pointer value, not a variable value.  So you can use *pointer arithmetic* on it.  So a + 1 will be equivalent to &(a[1]).  This is why a statement like this:

int *p = a, *p2 = a + 1;

is allowed.  Since pointers can point at both variables and array elements, if you write p[1], the compiler will assume p is pointing to an array, which in this example is correct, so p[1] is the same array element  as a[1].  *(p2 - 1) and p2[-1] both refer to the same array element as a[0] in this example.

Comment: only certain expressions perform the transformation you describe; `&a` and `sizeof a` are examples of expressions that do not

Comment: @M.M yes, sizeof is an exception.  The trade-off between full accuracy and overwhelming newbs with detail is a difficult one.